# Datacenter infrastructure - Planning a high-availability infrastructure

Tags: infrastructure, iscsi, san

I'm new to Datacenter infrastructure and I'm solving some exercises. I came across a question that I can't answer so I'm hero to ask some help. The question is:

1) In planning a high availability infrastructure with 20 machines on wich I'm gonna need a SAN, someone propose me 3 distinct solutions:

- a) A solution based on optical fibre switches to connect the machines
  to the SAN without redundancy.
- b) A solution completely based on iscsi;
- c) A solution that allows me to connect only to 8 machines to a SAN with redundancy;

Since none of this solutions is the ideal, which could be the solution/changes that could be recomended in order to ensure the access to storage from all the machines? Why

Please some help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me give you an answer that doesn't include a, b or c.

What I would do is go with a virtualized architecture (I will use VM-Ware as an example here) where you move as many as possible of the machines into your virtualized solution.

On a hardware level you set up a SAN with dual SAN-Switches. The switches are wired to Fibre-Channel HBA:s per machine. The actual machines would probably be Blades in a Blade Center.

Each Blade should be stuffed with as much power as you can, 2 x 10-Core CPU:s is a good choice. In that way you can fit as many virtual machines in as few blades as possible.

Since you are talking H/A you most likely want to have redundancy enough to loose one full Blade and have the machines restarted on the remaining Blades without affecting the performance too badly.

Online Service / Maintencance can be handled by products like V-Motion.

Based on this set up, you can continue building a H/A clustered environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switches with more ports, or you can use a distribution topology where additional switches provide additional conectivity for additional servers.

```
server  === \
server  ==== \
server =========FC Switch 1 ===two X connections  FCSwitch3
server =========FC Switch 2 ===two X connections  FCSwitch4
server  ==== /
server  === /
```